# Adding a call to a generic method within an open generic in Fody

Tags: c#, mono.cecil, fody

I'm attempting to weave a method call using Fody to fix an issue that causes some incompatibility between ReactiveUI and PropertyChanged.Fody

Now the implementation works just fine for all of my test cases except one - weaving it into an open generic type.

Here are the important bits:

1. Creating the method reference

```cs
            //get the method to call
            var reactiveExRaiseMethod = FindTypeDefinition("ReactiveUI.IReactiveObjectExtensions").GetMethods().Single(x => x.Name == "RaisePropertyChanged");
            var reactiveExRaiseMethodRef = ModuleDefinition.ImportReference(reactiveExRaiseMethod);

            var raiseMethod = reactiveExRaiseMethodRef.MakeGenericMethod(type);
```

2. Generating the IL

```cs
            var il = method.Body.GetILProcessor();
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, raiseMethod);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

3. `MakeGenericMethod` (not sure if this is correct - found on another post along the way)

```cs
        public static MethodReference MakeGenericMethod(this MethodReference self, params TypeReference[] arguments)
        {
            if (self.GenericParameters.Count != arguments.Length)
                throw new ArgumentException();

            var instance = new GenericInstanceMethod(self);
            foreach (var argument in arguments)
                instance.GenericArguments.Add(argument);

            return instance;
        }
```

4. Calling this code

```cs
  public class ReactiveObjectPropertyChangeFix : BaseModuleWeaver
    {
        public override void Execute()
        {
            foreach (var type in ModuleDefinition.Types)
            {
                VisitType(type); //this subsequently passes this reference to the code shown above
            }
```

Running this it works fine for everything except the open generic type

When i look at the generated code in ILSpy i see that it generates this:

```cs
public class MyReactiveObject<T> : ReactiveObject
{
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        ((MyReactiveObject<>)this).RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }
}
```

Instead of this (taken from the passing testcase object):

```cs
public class MyReactiveObject : ReactiveObject
{
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }
}
```

I know that there is something wrong with the reference created by `MakeGenericReference()` but I can't work out what it is, the error upon running the code on a closed generic instance (e.g. `MyReactiveObject<string>`) is:

> System.TypeLoadException : Could not load type 'Weavers.Tests.MyReactiveObject`1' from assembly 'Weavers.Tests, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it - an open generic type like this needs to be "closed" using the open generic type parameters. (Which makes complete sense when you think about it)

```cs
        public static MethodReference MakeGenericMethod(this MethodReference self, params TypeReference[] arguments)
        {
            if (self.GenericParameters.Count != arguments.Length)
                throw new ArgumentException();

            var instance = new GenericInstanceMethod(self);
            foreach (var argument in arguments.Select(MakeTypeReference).ToArray())
                instance.GenericArguments.Add(argument);

            return instance;

            TypeReference MakeTypeReference(TypeReference t)
            {
                if (t.HasGenericParameters && !t.IsGenericInstance)
                {                   
                    //this is the magic here - if we are passed an open generic then "close" it with the it's own type parameters
                    return t.MakeGenericType(t.GenericParameters.Select(x => (TypeReference)x).ToArray());
                }

                return t;
            }
        }
```